# 700Mb "netinst" ISO available for Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: boot, system-installation, iso

I've got several older Macs (2008-09 vintage) and they will only boot to CDROM (700Mb) media (No DVD 4.7Ghz or USB boot...).  I'd like to install Ubuntu on these old machines but am at an impasse since I can't find an ISO with just the essential files to get the ball rolling, and then download the other files once it's installing and network connection has been established.

I have installed Debian 12.2 this way, as Debian still has a <700Mb "netinst" iso available for CD optical media (v.12.4 was just released yesterday I believe).
https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-12.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso

Does anyone know if there is such an image available for Ubuntu, or could they point in the right direction so I could possibly build my own?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can boot into a CD with [Plop](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/bootUSB#PLoP_Boot_Manager) and from there chainload to a USB drive.

Comment: Please be aware that recent versions of Ubuntu require more resources than, say, Debian XFCE/LXDE. If Debian works for you, then just stick with it.

Comment: Yu do not need a cd/dvd/usb. you can boot from an ISO saved on disk from grub, "I'd like to install Ubuntu on these old machines" 2008? are those 64-bit? Ubuntu does not do 32-bit. ' have installed Debian 12.2 this way,' why not change the repo's to Ubuntu and have it replace debian?

Comment: "*I have installed Debian 12.2 this way, as Debian still has a <700Mb "netinst" iso available for CD optical media *" Creating the netinst image is part of the workflow of creating the Debian installer. Ubuntu has migrated away from using the Debian installer and has a different workflow to create the different installer.

Answer (score 1):

The final Ubuntu (20.04) netinstall mini.iso (74MB) is available at http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/

- This image has never been supported by the Ubuntu developer community. They won't answer questions about it, they won't make changes to it, and they won't fix reported bugs.

  The community is welcome to re-introduce netinstall images. Nothing is stopping a group of interested users from restarting that work.

For most users on common equipment, the normal Ubuntu Desktop installer includes a Minimal option for users who want to configure a lean system manually. The Ubuntu installers also read Preseed or CloudInit files for automated configuration.

Users who really need a lightweight bare-metal install on uncommon  equipment should look at [PXE installs](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/netbooting-the-live-server-installer/14510).

Cloud/VM/Container users should use lightweight [Ubuntu cloud images](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/) (~400-600MB). These won't work on bare metal.